# If $f(a) \leq 0$, $f(b) < 0$ and $\int_{a}^b f(x)\text{dx} \geq 0$ for $f: [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$, then $f'(x_0) = 0$.

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, definite-integrals

Let $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ with $a < b$ and $f : [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ be differentiable with
$$
f(a) \leq 0, \quad f(b) < 0 \quad \text{and} \quad \int_{a}^b f(x)\text{dx} \geq 0.
$$
I have to show that there exists a $x_0 \in (a,b)$ with $f'(x_0) = 0$.

Here is my attempt: From the mean-value theorem I know that there exists a point $c \in (a,b)$ such that
$$
f'(c) = \frac{f(b) - f(a)}{b-a}
$$
and from the mean value theorem for definite integrals I know that there exists some point $\xi \in [a,b]$ such that
$$
\int_{a}^b f(x)\text{dx} = f(\xi)(b-a).
$$
From here I don't know what to do next. Can someone give me a tip how I can continue? The case $f (a) = f (b)$ is clear, so that we can assume that $f (a) \neq f(b)$.

Comment: Hint: By the assumptions the function has at least 2 zeroes in $(a,b)$...

Answer (score 1):

well if:
$$\int_a^bf(x)dx\ge0$$
then that means that the mean value of $f$ over $[a,b]$ is also greater than or equal to zero i.e. $\bar{f}_{a,b}\ge0$
this means there exists a domain $[c,d]$ where $f>0$ where $a<c<d<b$. Now since $f(b)<0$ there has to be a maximum in $[c,d]$, which means there is also a maximum in $[a,b]$ i.e. a point where $f'(x_0)=0$